# Installing imagick on Centos7 with php7?

Tags: php, centos, imagick, centos7, php-7

I am trying to install imagick with this command

```
yum install php-pecl-imagick
```

This results in this error, I think it's because I am using php7 and not php5

> Error: php70u-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64

How can I download imagicks new version for use with php7 and centos7?

Comment: [I found it in approximately 8 seconds](https://gist.github.com/nivv/5d9a12af5472b91606e6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove packages php* , then install php70u .

Answer (score 1):

Subscribing to the IUS Community Project Repository
Since PHP 7.x is not yet packaged in official repositories for the major distributions, we’ll have to rely on a third-party source. Several repositories offer PHP 7 RPM files. We’ll use the IUS repository.

IUS offers an installation script for subscribing to their repository and importing associated GPG keys. Make sure you’re in your home directory, and retrieve the script using curl:

```
curl 'https://setup.ius.io/' -o setup-ius.sh
sudo bash setup-ius.sh
```

Install Required Packages-:

```
sudo yum install -y mod_php70u php70u-cli php70u-mysqlnd php70u-json php70u-gd php70u-dom php70u-simplexml php70u-mcrypt php70u-intl
```

for more details see my Article [install-php7-centos7/rhel](http://gotechnies.com/install-magento2-php7-centos7rhel/)